# why Is there no unique translation of source language into generated language in compilation process?

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization

Is there any algorithm or any compiler that translates exactly the source code into generated code when we compile our code?

Comment: What do you mean by "generated code"? Technically all compilers do this (if you consider machine code to be _code_)

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly"? What "generated code" are you talking about?

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about transpiling/transcompiling - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler

Comment: in some books it is said that when we compile any program then source code is not able to generate the required output due to some compiler flaws.

Comment: I suppose "generated code" might refer to the IR generated by the semantic analyzer here. However, your question is way too simplistic and lacking essential details that might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated two completely different questions and I will try to answer them one at a time. First, the question on why there i no unique transformation from source to target code when compiling. This is due to the fact that with most computer languages, as with natural languages, there is usually many ways to express the same idea or algorithm and, analogous with natural language, you choose the wording depending on the context. Thus when compiling you take the source code and transform it to target code by choosing the words that work best in the context that the target code should work in. If your program must be fast you choose target constructions that are fast and if your program must work in a memory-constrained environment you choose compact target constructions.

The answer to the second question, i.e. if there is any compiler that translates exactly the source code into target code, is that this is what all compilers aim to do and if they fail this is due to bugs. To generalize things a bit, this implies that for simple programs all compilers will translate the source into equivalent target code while they may fail on code that are using the more complex parts of the source language.